# .htaccess rewrite rule pattern match

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a lot of old url's I would like to redirect that follow this pattern
en-gb/news/********** that need to go to the new url of new-and-events/news/
is there one rewrite rule I could use for all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_alias for this by adding this directive to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Redirect /en-gb/news/ /news-and-events/news/
```

can add a 301 right after the `Redirect` if you want it to be a permanent redirect. This will redirect a URL like `http://example.com/en-gb/news/anything` to `http://example.com/news-and-events/news/anything`.

I assume by *"new-and-events/"* you mean *"**news**-and-events/"*.